# Test-Connection mystery

Tags: powershell, wmi, ping, remote-server

We have been using a powershell script to ping some of our servers. The script worked fine until recently, Test-Connection $machineName -quiet returns $false even though the machine is fine! (ping $machineName works fine, even Test-Connection $machineName -quiet outside the script works fine). The first thing that came to my mind is to ckeck the user permissions. Is there anything I can do to run more test ?

Comment: Post your code and someone might be able to help

Comment: Perhaps removing the `-Quiet` might help in pinpointing the reason.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The code is as simple as         if ((test-connection $hostname -count 1 -quiet) -eq $true)
        { ...do stuff } else { ..do other stuff}
I still think it related to the user! but cannot quite figure out how/ why this happened. I am yet to replicate the problem!

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Specifying the source machine helped me identify what the problem is. test-connection -source $machine1 -computername $machine2. This will run test-connection from $machine1 rather than localhost.

Comment: Are you sure $hostname or $machinename is set correctly (which is it)?

Answer (score 0):

try casting the test-connection as a bool.

```
if ( [bool](test-connection $hostname -count 1 -quiet) -eq $true) { ...do stuff } else { ..do other stuff}
```